# Didn't work convert JSON decoded string to array in PHP which is send by Ajax method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have JS object

```
data=[{'quest':'sometext'},{'option':['a','b', 'c']}, {'cor':[0,1,0]},{'sol':'again tetx'}]
```

Submited as Ajax data using JQuery

```
... data:{'qs':JSON.stringify(data)}, ...
```

I received the as post and try to convert to array

```
$array=json_decode(json_encode($_POST['qs']), true);
```

but output is

```
print_r($array); \\is

[{"quest":"sometext"},{"option":["a","b", "c"]}, {"cor":[0,1,0]},{"sol":"again tetx'}]
```

I want to make it array in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = json_decode($_POST['qs'], true);
print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [quest] => sometext
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [option] => Array
                (
                    [0] => a
                    [1] => b
                    [2] => c
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [cor] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 1
                    [2] => 0
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [sol] => again tetx
        )

)
```